# Representing an equation

Tags: java, android, math

I'm new into Java/Android Studio, so I'm having trouble trying to represent the following equation on Android Studio (especially the e and potential part):
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as

```
 Pt = P0 * Math.exp(K * s * (t -t0));
```

Note that you might have to declare Pt as a double and the others as int, float etc.

For example:

```
double Pt = 0;
```